# ACVF and PACF of MA(q)?

Tags: time-series

1. [Brockwell and Davis's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=VHB4OSAmwcUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false) gives the autocovariance of a MA(q)
   process. I wonder if the magnitude of its autocovariance
   monotonically decreases before the lag $h$ increases over $q$?

   [image]
2. [A note](http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/bloomfield/courses/st730/slides/sns-03-3.pdf) says the PACF of a MA(q) process tails off. Does the magnitude of the PACF of a MA(q) process decrease as the
   lag increases? If yes, does it decrease exponentially?

   Is there derivation of the PACF of a MA(q) process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a formula for calculating the autocorrelations. Using them and the following formula (from [Wei (2005)](http://www.amazon.de/Time-Series-Analysis-Univariate-Multivariate/dp/0321322169) P. 15) you can calculate the partial autocorrelations.

[image]

Furthermore, you can calculate the PACF as regression coefficients regressing $Z_{t+k}$ on its $k$ lagged variables $Z_{t+k-1}, Z_{t+k-2}\dots,Z_t$.